# Remover elementos de uma Lista em Python

Tags: python, lista

Estou com um problema com listas no Python. Eu tenho uma lista em 2 variáveis diferentes com o mesmo valor, mas se removo um elemento de qualquer uma das listas, a lista que era pra ficar intacta também tem seu elemento removido.

```
listaUm = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listaDois = listaUm
listaDois.remove(3)
#listaDois [1, 2, 4]
#listaUm [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A referência do `listaDois` está igual ao do `listaUm`, quando você fez `listaDois = listaUm`. Por isso, quando altera um está alterando o outro.

Tente copiar o array desta forma: `listaDois = [n for n in listaUm]`

**EDIT:** Conforme sugerido pelo @drgarcia1986 nos comentários, uma forma equivalente também é:

> listaDois = **list**(listaUm)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, resolveu o meu problema!

Comment: uma forma mais fácil é `listaDois = list(listaUm)`

Comment: Por que isso acontece? Que referência é essa que está sendo copiada? Poderia desenvolver melhor essa parte?

Answer (score 9):

O problema da sua solução é que ambas as listas (`listaUm` e `listaDois`) referenciam o mesmo lugar na memória.

```
listaUm = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listaDois = listaUm.copy() # Tire uma copia da listaUm
listaDois.remove(3)
print(listaUm)
print(listaDois)
```

Como saída, é  esperado `[1,2,3,4]` e `[1,2,4]`.

Atenção com o comando `del`, pois o mesmo não deve ser utilizado em iterações, podendo gerar erros de indexação

Answer (score 3):

Use o *statement* `del`:

```
>>> a = [-1, 1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> del a[0]
>>> a
[1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> del a[2:4]
>>> a
[1, 66.25, 1234.5]
>>> del a[:]
>>> a
[]
```

[Fonte](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

Comment: tentei com o del, e deu o mesmo problema... mas a solução de cima deu certinho, vlw pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Uma das forma válidas para resolver este problema é realizando uma **cópia profunda** de *listaUm*.

Este processo pode ser obtido utilizando o método **[deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)** da biblioteca **[copy](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/copy.html)**

**OBSERVAÇÃO:**

*Uma cópia profunda constrói um novo objeto composto e então, recursivamente, insere nele cópias dos objetos encontrados no original.*

Desta forma podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from copy import deepcopy

listaUm = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listaDois = deepcopy(listaUm)
listaDois.remove(3)

print(listaUm)
print(listaDois)
```

Observe que este código, inicialmente, define **listaDois** como sendo uma cópia profunda da **listaUm**. Dessa forma, **listaDois** é uma cópia fiel de **listaUm** só que em outro endereço de memória.

Então, a partir deste momento poderemos remover quaisquer valor de **listaDois** sem interferir em **listaUm**.

Executando o referido código, obtemos como saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
```