# Retirar elementos de uma lista

Tags: python

```
['# cultura de alface (parcial)\n', 'volume:5:0.25:m3\n', 'PH:7.5:0.45:-\n', 'nitrato de calcio:750:51:ppm\n', 'nitrato de potassio:500:45:ppm\n', 'sulfato de magnesio:400:25:ppm\n', 'sulfato de manganes:1.5:0.45:ppm\n', 'fosfato monoamonico:150:40:ppm\n', 'detritos:100:50:ppm\n', '\n']
```

Tenho a lista acima e quero retirar de 'volume:5:0.25:m32\n' só o 5 e o 0.25 separadamente

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Remover elementos de uma Lista Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74015/remover-elementos-de-uma-lista-python)

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função `split` para quebrar uma string em uma lista de substrings à partir de um separador. No seu caso utilize o separador ':' para o item `'volume:5:0.25:m3\n'`. Dessa forma a função retornará uma lista `['volume', '5', '0.25', 'm3\n']`. Os itens 1 e 2 são os que você necessita.

```
In [1]: v = ['# cultura de alface (parcial)\n', 'volume:5:0.25:m3\n', 'PH:7.5:0.45:-\n', 'nitrato de calcio:750:51:ppm\n', 'nitrato de potassio:500:45:ppm\n', 'sulfato de magnesio:400:25:ppm\n', 'sulfato de manganes:1.5:0.45:ppm\n', 'fosfato monoamonico:150:40:ppm\n', 'detritos:100:50:ppm\n', '\n']

In [2]: v[1].split(':')[1]
Out[2]: '5'

In [3]: v[1].split(':')[2]
Out[3]: '0.25'
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que você procura seja o `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`, mesmo. Dada uma `string`, esse método criará uma lista com cada um dos itens dessa `string`, que poderão ser acessados por um índice. Veja o código:

```
# criamos a sua lista, com todas as entradas
lista = ['# cultura de alface (parcial)\n', 'volume:5:0.25:m3\n', 'PH:7.5:0.45:-\n',
         'nitrato de calcio:750:51:ppm\n', 'nitrato de potassio:500:45:ppm\n',
         'sulfato de magnesio:400:25:ppm\n', 'sulfato de manganes:1.5:0.45:ppm\n',
         'fosfato monoamonico:150:40:ppm\n', 'detritos:100:50:ppm\n', '\n']

# e mais duas listas de apoio
nova_lista = []
resultado_consulta = []

for elemento in lista: # para cada elemento nesta lista
    provisorio = elemento.strip('\n') # removemos a nova linha -> '\n'
    # e separamos as informações usando os dois pontos:
    nova_lista.append(provisorio.split(':'))

for dado in nova_lista: # para cada informação nessa nova lista
    if "volume" in dado: # procuramos por essa string (volume nesse caso)
        for valor in dado: # ao encontrar, percorremos esse registro
            resultado_consulta.append(valor) # adicionando em 'resultado_consulta'
        break # depois de encontrar 'volume', paramos

print('Mostrando apenas as informações de ' + resultado_consulta[0] + ':')
print(resultado_consulta[1] + ', ' + resultado_consulta[2])
```

---

A lista `resultado consulta` terá mais de um elemento, que poderão ser acessados através de índices (começando no zero), por exemplo:

```
resultado_consulta[0] # o item 0 neste caso será 'volume'
resultado_consulta[1] # e o 1, será '5'
resultado_consulta[2] # e o 2, será '0.25'
resultado_consulta[3] # e o 3, será 'm3'
resultado_consulta[4] # e o 4, será: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Porque não existe o elemento 5 nessa lista!

> Resultado:
>   [image: resultado da execução do programa]